# Issue detecting broken images when using JS to reset an array of displayed images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, image

I am fairly inexperienced with Javascript, but I've been struggling with something that doesn't feel like it should be this hard. I'm trying to have my script check an image that has been loaded to see if it's valid (Not a missing file), and if it is missing, to reset the image array to item 0 and repeat, as I can assume it has reached the end of available images in the dir when it encountered a missing file.

I need to reserve several hardcoded image names in a local directory for a slideshow display, but in the event there are more reserved names than images, I need it to reset rather than display broken images.

I cannot make use of PHP or HTML5 for a more straightforward and dynamic solution. I've tried several attempts and I'm just out of ideas here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Monitor Display<title>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <base href="file://c:/LocalDir/"/>


        <!-- CSS -->
        <style>
            .images { 
                position:relative; margin:-8px; max-width:100%; height:auto;}
            .images img { 
                position:absolute; left:0; top:0; margin:-8px; max-width:100%; height:auto;}
            body {
                background-color:rgb(51,51,51);}
        </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <!-- Animation -->
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        changeImage();
    });

    function changeImage() {
        var img = $('.images img');

        if(x >= (images.length-1)) { 
            x = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            x++;
        }

        img[0].src = images[x];
        setTimeout("changeImage()", 5000);
    }

    var images = [],
    x = 0;

    images[0] = "ThumbChart0big.png";
    images[1] = "ThumbChart1big.png";
    images[2] = "ThumbChart2big.png";
    images[3] = "ThumbChart3big.png";
    </script>   
    <!-- Image Container -->
    <div class="images">
        <img src="ThumbChart1big.png"/>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .error() :

```
....
var x = 0;
function changeImage() {
    var img = $('.images img');
    img.error( function() {
      x = 0;  // reset the array index
    });
   //continue...
```